# Branchless version of swapping x with y if x > y?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization

Assuming `x` and `y` are signed integers, is there some super efficient trick for implementing:

```
if (x < y) {
    std::swap(x, y);
}
```

I can instantly think of a solution using `c = x < y` and then you assign `x` to `c * x + (1 - c) * y` etc. but this approach emits multiplication instructions, which I would like to avoid. Is there a way to do this with bit fiddling alone?

EDIT: Just clarifying that what I really care about is trying to get rid of the branch caused by the `if`. In other words, I'm aware of the XOR trick to do a swap, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: compilers are smart - why are you worrying about this?

Comment: OK. May be, it's worth to mention in your question what you wrote in your comment (to make this point clear).

Comment: I'm worrying about this, because I've checked with the compiler explorer and I see a branch being emitted in the assembly with both clang and gcc. In other words, they're not smart, assuming a trick for optimizing this exists.

Comment: You forgot to put the "if (x < y) {...}" around the swap in your code sample. If you add that, you'll see a branch being emitted. I wouldn't ask the question unless this was in a latency critical inner loop being called billions of times...

Comment: Concerning `?:`, another [**Sample on godbolt**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/VZI2p2).

Comment: [**Sample on godbolt**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/E3CFNi)  For me, it looks that there is no real swapping - just writing registers back if necessary. Anyway, I would count on the compiler and not worry too much about such details. We're speeking about a few cycles. Do you intend to repeat this a [mb]illion times?

Comment: Whether or not it is possible do get rid of the branching depends on the CPU, I suppose (e.g., the above links to gobolt are based on Intel-like stuff)

Comment: Extending the idea with `?:`, I find it remarkable that gcc introduces the branching as soon as it finds two nearly identical conditions with `?:` (where it used `cmpmvle` when there was only one): [**Sample on godbolt**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Vhil6Y)

Comment: branching isn't always slow, provided that the comparison is predictable (and CPUs are really good at it). Your code is like `X = x; Y = y; x = std::max(X, Y); y = std::min(X, Y);` which can be easily done without a branch, but needs 2 `cmovcc` which may be slower than a branch. In my experience ICC uses `cmovcc` more than Clang, which in turn emits those instructions more frequently than gcc. [Sample](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/j8xrWN)

Comment: If branches really are that expensive, I'd consider using a couple of temporaries  `X = std::max(x, y); Y = std::min(x,y); x = X; y = Y;`.    Practically, however, seeing a branch being emitted in the compiler explorer is insufficient justification - I'd want to see evidence in the form of actual performance/profiling data, rather than simply ASSUMING it is necessary to eliminate a branch.

Comment: **Almost all the above alternatives simply replace a easy to see branch with one that is slightly less apparent in code**. `c = x < y` or `?:` or `std::max` all contains a condition which will essentially resolve to a branch (or 2). In most sample, alternative code is more complex and probably slower. **If there is an optimization, the compiler probably knot it anyway**. Except when profiling show a reel performance problem, avoid micro-optimization that make code harder to understand. And if you write such code anyway, ensure that the performance gain is big enough to justify it.

Comment: As a mathematician I can prove to you that there exists a solution (even if I don't know what the solution is). You might want to try a mathematics site possibly. I'm going to spend the evening thinking about this, which will make me poor company.

Comment: Have you benchmarked this code vs inline assembly using `cmp`/`mov`/`cmovele`/`cmovl` ([the code clang emits](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/gNlNlu))? [Sometimes branching is faster than a conditional move](https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/cmov.html) ([here's another reference](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26306)). If you can spread out the `cmp` from the `cmov` it might help too.

Comment: If you have SSE4 available, you can do this for 4 integers at the same time using one `pmaxsd` and `pminsd` instruction (and a possibly a copy). You need to show more context to clarify if that makes sense (or optimizing makes sense at all here ...)

Answer (score 5):

I not sure, is this speedp your code, but this is branchless solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int a = atoi(argv[1]);
  int b = atoi(argv[2]);
  int c = a - b;
  c &= c >> 31; // SXT for signed int
  a -= c;
  b += c;
  printf("Result: %d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

Comment: `>> 31` invokes implementation-defined behavior, doesn't it?

Comment: 31 is architecture-dependent. You can use more correct, but more ugly: (sizeof(int)*8 - 1)

Comment: It's not just about 31 or 8 (`CHAR_BIT`). It's also about negative values. You may want `-(c < 0)` instead of `c >> 31`. And the whole code still relies on 2's complement representation.

Comment: Thanks for hint, it is nice. I compared both variants, clang generates exactly same code for both. However, (c < 0), depends on implementation, has risk to be branched by some compiler. My core clearly branchless.

Comment: With modern compilers there's no guarantee there is or there is no branch. :)

Answer (score 2):

In case `x` and `y` are written to memory after this operation then you might be able to use write to dynamic memory location instead of conditional jump. For example to sort `a[0], a[1]`:

```
int x = a[0];
int y = a[1];
a[x >= y] = x;
a[y > x] = y;
```

If you need to read the values back immediately, then it will likely be slower than even predictable branch, but it might depend on processor.

Comment: Building off of this, you could perform a swap by `int a[2] = {x, y}; int lt = x < y; x = a[lt]; y = a[lt ^ 1];`. Though I don't expect that to perform better that the original code.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to implement swapping is to recognize that you have names and data associated with the names, and that you can swap the names instead of swapping the data.

For example, a compiler can convert this:

```
if (x < y) {
    std::swap(x, y);
}
do_something(x, y);
return x;
```

..into this:

```
if (x < y) {
    // Names of "x" and "y" swapped in subsequent code
    do_something(y, x);
    return y;
} else {
    do_something(x, y);
    return x;
}
```

Of course swapping the names and not swapping the data is often free (for performance) because you're not actually swapping anything.

**Modern CPUs do this exact same trick.**

Specifically; a CPU has registers, and registers are names associated with data. For an instruction like `xchg eax,ebx` (on 80x86), the CPU will just swap the register names and won't move the data. This means that the CPU can do the swap when the data in either register is not known yet (e.g. because it's still being calculated or fetched by a previous instruction).

In other words; the fastest way to implement `std::swap(x, y);` is to ensure that the right instruction is generated for the CPU (e.g. so that the CPU is given an `xchg eax,ebx` on 80x86, which has no branches and doesn't have to wait until the values are known).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, you may try rewriting your code in terms of `std::min()` and `std::max()`.

But there's no guarantee. The language simply lacks a means of expressing what you want from the compiler.

About the only other non-C++ solution I may offer would be inline assembly, where you can write precisely the instructions you desire. However, using inline assembly affects what the compiler does with the code around it and there may be negative impact (e.g. inefficient use of registers, register spills and such) that may offset or negate any anticipated gains.

Comment: Who says that `std::min` and `std::max` do not branch? The gcc library implements this basically just as `if(b>a) return b; else return a;`, see https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h

Comment: @Handy999 I think you don't get it. There's no guarantee there would be or would be no branch. It's entirely up to the compiler and there's no language construct to definitively tilt the compiler to emit one or prohibit from emitting one.

Comment: This is and was completely clear to me and I completely do agree that you do not have direct control about what code is created! Nonetheless, I consider the idea of min and max being non-branching constructs to be completely ridiculous since they are functions that do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following, which compiles down to 3 or 4 instructions:

```c
static inline void sortMinMax(uint32_t *aPtr, uint32_t *bPtr) {
    uint32_t a=*aPtr, b=*bPtr;
    *aPtr = a < b ? a : b;
    *bPtr = a < b ? b : a;
}
```

Example usage:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

static inline void sortMinMax(uint32_t *aPtr, uint32_t *bPtr) {
    uint32_t a=*aPtr, b=*bPtr;
    *aPtr = a < b ? a : b;
    *bPtr = a < b ? b : a;
}

int main() {
    uint32_t randMax = rand(), randMin = rand();
    
    sortMinMax(&randMin, &randMax);

    printf("Min random number: %" PRIu32 "\n", randMin);
    printf("Max random number: %" PRIu32 "\n", randMax);
}
```

Godbolt: https://sortminmax.godbolt.org/z/enWdavsW4

(Note: do not use `rand` in real code outside demos like this.)